# How to create a React app without webpack and Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

without using webpack and create-react-app how to create a React app

i would like to use following in my react application
1.redux
2.react routing

Comment: https://github.com/misterfresh/react-without-webpack

i tried above link but could not understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609910/react-without-webpack

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the cdn and implement your component to the project. That is if you have already a web page and you want to implement a few components with reactJs.  Check this page has your answer.
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html