# Minimal React setup without Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed this answer here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50066512/11420374

But after compiling my Browser (Firefox 67) says:

> **SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

---

My app.jsx looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Alpha extends React.Component {render() { return <h1>Hello</h1>; }}
ReactDOM.render(<Alpha />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="js/dashboard.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

compiled using babel-cli

---

Why is that? They said that newer browsers support es6 imports.

Tried:

```
... type="module"></script>
```

Result:

> **TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: react**

Comment: My first thought is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415925/3000068. Does that answer your question?

Comment: getting: TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: react

Comment: Browsers unlike node.js, cannot resolve path names,.. So you might need to do `import React from './react';` instead, assuming your react files are in the same directory, or maybe `import React from '/lib/react'` etc.

Comment: cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:...

Comment: It looks like you've been down voted without feedback. If helpful I can try to make sense of it and explain.  I guess one thing they expected was a direct question up front before any other information.  For example the title or first line of the question could say "How can a React build be configured for scenario xyz?" or, "How can React syntax error xyz be fixed?", etc.  If you wouldn't mind trying an edit for this I'd be glad to support your effort with +1.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm no fan of  `<script type="module">` solution. I'd recommend an alternative.

Give [parcel](https://parceljs.org) bundler a try. It is a *zero config* CLI tool.

First, install globally

```
npm install -g parcel-bundler
```

All you need to do is modify your `index.html` to ref the *source code path* directly like:

```
...
    <script src="src/app.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then type in terminal

```
parcel index.html
```

You're good to go!

Comment: thanks, i think parcel is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal React setup without `webpack`:

```js
const {render} = ReactDOM
const {createElement: h} = React

function GreatSuccess(props) {
  return h('h1', null, 'Hello ', props.framework)
}

render(h(GreatSuccess, {framework: 'React'}),
  document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Some of the ways in which this differs from your code:

- You're using JSX, which is non-standard. Use `React.createElement()` instead
- Your code assumes Node.js module resolution rules. Either `import './path/to/react.js'`<sup>***1**</sup> or better yet, just load React via a `<script>` tag

***1**: Last time I checked this didn't work, due to bug [#14635](//github.com/facebook/react/issues/14635)